# Federate .NET MVC application with SAML using Sustainsys / Saml2

Tags: .net, saml-2.0, sustainsys-saml2

Currently windows authentication is being used by our web app. We need to integrate this to an existing single sign on with SAML. I am looking with [Sustainsys / Saml2](https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2) to integrate our web app with SAML.

Our site homepage url is this: 
    http://siteName/Home/Index

IdP endpoint: 
    https://providerName.com:8080/idp/start/sso.ping?PartnerSpid=mySite

When I try to navigate to saml single sign on and enter my credential I am being redirected to our site: http://siteName/Home/Index 
So I supposed that saml environment setup is working correctly

My problem now is, when I navigate to our site homepage, if the user is not yet authenticated, I want it to redirect first to Idp endpoint to authenticate the user: https://providerName.com:8080/idp/start/sso.ping?PartnerSpid=mySite

Here's the current web.config I'm trying:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <section name="system.identityModel.services" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelServicesSection, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <section name="sustainsys.saml2" type="Sustainsys.Saml2.Configuration.SustainsysSaml2Section, Sustainsys.Saml2" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <add name="Saml2AuthenticationModule" type="Sustainsys.Saml2.HttpModule.Saml2AuthenticationModule, Sustainsys.Saml2.HttpModule" />
    </modules>
    <security>
        <authentication>
            <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
        </authentication>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
  <sustainsys.saml2 entityId="https://providerName.com:8080/idp/start/sso.ping?PartnerSpid=mySite" returnUrl="https://providerName.com:8080/idp/start/sso.ping?PartnerSpid=mySite">
    <identityProviders>
      <add entityId="https://providerName.com:8080/pf/federation_metadata.ping?PartnerSpId=mySite" signOnUrl="https://providerName.com:8080/idp/start/sso.ping?PartnerSpid=mySite" allowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse="true" binding="HttpRedirect">
        <signingCertificate fileName="~/App_Data/Saml2.cer" />
      </add>
    </identityProviders>
  </sustainsys.saml2>
  <system.identityModel.services>
    <federationConfiguration>
      <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" name="SampleMvcApplicationAuth" />
    </federationConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel.services>
```

Comment: Usually for SSO modules to kick start the negotiation, it is sufficient your local resources return 401/403 when accessed. I presmuse the `Saml2AuthModule` from sustainsys could do the same. Make your local page guarded with `Authorize` (if it's MVC) and test then.

Comment: it has an Authorize attribute in the controller's action.

Answer (score 4):

The redirect is handled by setting authentication mode to form.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Saml2/SignIn" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: Thanks Anders, It works, but now my problem is that everytime I navigate to Action that has [Authorize] attribute, it always go to the idp login page (without needing to type credentials) and will redirect to my homepage. In your project example it's Home/Secure -> I can't navigate here it always goes to homepage. PS: Idp callback is my homepage